# Page Indexing > Page with Redirect to Google Search Console

Tags: seo, redirects

I need help. My website URL is like https://example.com/.
I have a problem with page indexing with redirect.
There are shown `Page Indexing > Page with Redirect` in Google Search Console. That's why I submitted a request from the `Removal` tab to remove these 3 URLs on May 7, 2023. But, I am getting the same message again with 3 URLs on Aug 6, 2023.
http://example.com/
http://www.example.com/
https://www.example.com/

**Note:** These 3 URL does not exist in sitemap which is uploded on Google Serch Console.

Thanks.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google's page indexing "issues" are often misnamed. In several cases (such as "blocked by robots.txt") what they are referring to as an "issue" is actually expected and even desired behaviour.

You possibly won't successfully remove these pages from the index, since as Google is pointing out, these pages aren't indexed because they're redirecting anyway.

It is likely that there are, or were, links pointing to these pages. And it is these links which are a potential issue if they still exist. A check of your content should identify internal links. External links might be more problematic, but allowing the 301 redirects to handle them isn't going to damage the SEO value of those backlinks overly, although if the owner of the linking website is amenable, you could ask for the destination URLs to be updated to be correct.

Just because there are pages listed as having indexing issues, it doesn't mean that would have a detrimental effect on your SEO performance. Although ensuring that links are targeted correctly would certainly improve their value to you.

Comment: GeoffAtkins@ Thanks a lot for your cooperation.